# How to dynamically load and call a symbol which has a library-specific type as a function parameter

Tags: c++, linux, fuse, dlopen, dlsym

Suppose I have the following:

```
// lib1.h
struct S 
{
    int x;
};
void f(S* s);  // defined in .cpp
```

and

```
// lib2.h
struct S 
{
    int x;
    int y;
};
void f(S* s);  // defined in .cpp
```

Resulting in `lib1.so` and `lib2.so`.

So, my question is:

```
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
    const auto lib_to_use = <some application level logic, resulting in lib1.so or lib2.so>;
    const auto lib = dlopen(lib_to_use, RTLD_LAZY);
    assert(lib);

    const auto func = dlsym(lib, "f");
    assert(func);

    // how do I call `func`, given the fact it takes different, library-specific type `S`?

    dlclose(lib);
}
```

---

**My real-world issue** is - how do I load at run-time `libfuse2` or `libfuse3` and execute `fuse_main_real`, given the fact it has `fuse_operations*` parameter, which is a `struct` with function pointers, but with different types for the two versions?

**Edit**: I don't believe this breaks the one-definition rule - only one of them will be linked at the same time, never both of them. (I'm also not sure if ODR is broken if both are loaded, as they are manually used, but that's another topic)

Comment: Do the structures really have the exact same name? Then you break [the one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#One_Definition_Rule).

Comment: Yes, they do. But I don't see how this breaks the ODR, they will never be loaded at the same time? I mean, only one of them will be loaded. (I'm not even sure if this breaks the ODR, given the fact `dlsym` is used, not just automatic dynamic linking)

Comment: As for the libraries, are they at all related? Are they *"your*" libraries (meaning you can edit them as much as you want)? Then why not use inheritance for the structures?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude they are not, I've written my real-world case - they are two different versions of `libfuse` (incompatible, but co-existing by design on the same machine)

Comment: Setting a bounty when you already have two answers seems strange. If you are dissatisfied with the answers so far, you should probably say why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the extent that the standard can be said to apply to dynamic objects, you’re right that there’s no ODR violation between multiple objects that are never loaded together (because there is no *program* that contains both definitions).  The same cannot be said for your program if it contains a definition of each class type (obviously) or contains a definition of one and (the runtime choice is that it) loads the dynamic object that uses the other.  (With DLLs the situation is stranger: types are shared but not their member functions, static data members, or RTTI symbols.)

The answer is to keep those definitions separate: **wrap** each dynamic object in one of your own (linked against it with a simple `-l`) that exposes a **common interface** (which must be possible for the question to make sense).  Load one or the other of *those* in your main program and call it using the unique type(s) `#include`d from that interface.

Comment: No idea why there's a down-vote here and I'm curious what's the reason behind it. Anyone? Because that's exactly what I thought I should do in order to workaround this limitation, so +1. I'll wait to see if a better answer will appear (without using such workaround).

Answer (score 2):

> how do I call `func`, given the fact it takes different, library-specific type `S`?

Obviously you can't have type `S` in your main program that matches both `lib1` `S` and `lib2` `S` at the same time. So you must declare two separate types: `S1` and `S2`.

The rest is trivial:

```
int version = which_version_should_I_use();
if (version == V1) {
  void *h = dlopen("lib1.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  void (*fn)(S1*) = (void (*)(S1*))dlsym(h, "f");
  assert(fn != NULL);
  S1 s = ...;
  fn(&s);
} else {
  // must be V2
  void *h = dlopen("lib2.so", RTLD_LAZY);
  void (*fn)(S2*) = (void (*)(S2*))dlsym(h, "f");
  assert(fn != NULL);
  S2 s = ...;
  fn(&s);
}
```

Comment: This is undefined behavior because the function is called through a function pointer of the wrong type.  (It surely works anyway.)